# Change font color on ribbon text- SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

What CSS tag controls the font color of the Share/Edit/etc text on the ribbon in SP 2013?

Basically I'm trying to change this color and I'm spinnng my wheels. Thanks.

Comment: Use F12 developer tools.

Comment: Not a SP developer, so I'm not getting very far with this.

Comment: If I select element by click, then click the text, it displays the properties of "ms-promotedActionButton-text".  Changing any of the 3 mentions in my css file changes nothing.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and choose F12 developer tools :)

Answer (score 2):

To change Edit, Share, Follow text have class named 'ms-promotedActionButton-text':

```
span.ms-promotedActionButton-text {
    color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, but here is my current text:

Comment: .ms-promotedActionButton-text
{
display:inline-block;
 color:#666;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:8pt;
}

Comment: What's the correct code?  Sorry, not a CSS coder and I'm lost.  I tried a few things and it made no difference.